# Probabilistic programming : reifying distributions and stuff?

Tags: prolog, probability, problog, webppl

Does ProbLog and/or prolog/cplint support working with distributions and reifying distributions, condition/observe, etc like the example below in WebPPL.

If yes how you do that ?

/I know cplint supports may be distributions, but reifying?/

```
// sampling function, condition() acts 
// like filter i.e. the match is excluded from sampling result
var test = function() {
    var a = flip() //Bernoulli
    var b = flip()
    condition(a||b)
    return {a:a,b:b}
}

//reifying a distribution
var abc = Infer({method: 'rejection', samples:1000}, test)
abc

$ webppl test2.wppl 
Marginal:
    {"a":false,"b":true} : 0.337
    {"a":true,"b":false} : 0.332
    {"a":true,"b":true} : 0.331
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Both ProbLog and cplint support conditional distributions (observations). Consider the following program:

```
0.5::a.
0.5::b.

q_a_and_b:- a,b.
q_or:- a.
q_or:- b.
```

In cplint, you can query given evidence as:

```
?- prob(q_a_and_b,q_or,Prob).
Prob = 0.33.
```

The same for ProbLog (you need to add the query and the evidence directly in your program). The previous query can be read as: ``what is the probability that `q_a_and_b` is true given that `q_or` has been observed?''. This solution adopts exact inference. In cplint you can use also approximate inference (with the MCINTYRE module), but for this sample program is not needed.

Comment: thanks, is it possible to mix&match i.e. go from marginalization/sampling dist to "exact interface" dist and back in the same program ...

Comment: in Problog how would you do Gaussian and other exact  dist ? can u somehow leverage numpy via python <==> problog or this can only be used for sampling

Comment: If you want to use continuous random variables (or both discrete and continuous) you should use cplint od HAL-ProbLog (known also ad DC-ProbLog). Anyway, you can use exact and approximate inference as you want: just write a rule that call exact and then approximate inference. Exact inference with continuous random variables can be performed with HAL-ProbLog (or DC-Problog). In cplint, you only have approximate inference based on sampling (rejection or MCMC).